# Twitter Cards Images Are Blurry

Tags: html, twitter, blogger, facebook-opengraph, twitter-card

Over the last weekend, I installed Twitter Cards on my Blogger blog, however, when I post a link to a post on Twitter, the preview image seems a bit blurry.

https://twitter.com/DailyNickNews/status/986395296350527488

https://twitter.com/DailyNickNews/status/986395007216209920

https://twitter.com/DailyNickNews/status/986394831470637056

When I open the image in a new tab, I get a URL such as

https://pbs.twimg.com/card_img/986394838189924352/9Nw874O_?format=jpg&name=600x314

However, the actual image size displayed is much smaller. In the above example, the image is 392x205.

The code I’m using is:

```
<b:comment> Twitter Cards for Blogger XML </b:comment>
<meta expr:content='data:view.featuredlmage ? &quot;summary_large_image&quot;: &quot;summary&quot;' name='twitter:card'/>
<meta content='https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-qANmiWyhUFg/WtPAtPo65NI/AAAAAAAA5Yw/CJoYJyvpUKMrKEGHxtj0vTLS_x9AJWyDQCLcBGAs/sl600/nickelodeon-logo-nick.png' property='og:image/>
<meta content='@ Daily NickNews' name='twitter:site'/>
<meta content='@ Daily NickNews' name='twitter:creator'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.homepageUrl.canonical' name='twitter:domain'/>
<meta expr:content='data:view.url.canonical' name='twitter:url'/>
<meta expr:content='data:view.title' name='twitter:title'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription ? data:view.description : &quot;&quot;' name='twitter:description'/>
<b:if cond='data:view.featuredImage'>
<meta expr:content='data:view.featuredlmage' name='twitter:image:src'/>
</b:if>
```

I’m a novice at Twitter Cards and have no idea what to change. The top META tag already says ‘summary_large_image’.

I've tried changing the value of the last META tag to twitter:image from twitter:image:src, however, nothing changed.

Comment: Twitter optimizes for size, not quality; don't expect much from it. Recommended minimum size (last time I checked; it may have changed) is 600x314, optimal is 1200x628. Straying from these proportions will result in resizing and loss of quality.

Comment: I was thinking that could be the problem. Is there a way to get Twitter to use the original image that the thumbnail links to?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the data tag `data:view.featuredlmage` which picks up the image size as set via the post editor. To make sure that the image size picked up by Twitter is always the largest, modify the code as follows -

```
<meta expr:content='resizeImage(data:blog.postImageUrl,1600)' name='twitter:image:src'/>
```

Comment: Hi @Prayag Verma, I've updated the code, but the quality hasn't changed. Weird thing now though is that I get a mix of card options on Twitter. They either show as a smaller card with no photo, a smaller card with a photo, or normal with low image quality. The code I'm using is https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ZG3RL4d6cPw/Wtt-UZdNfZI/AAAAAAAA5h8/eI0LcJ5u7rw-ai3sl8q5rrbN1MqQ9AH0gCLcBGAs/s1600/twitter-cards4.png

Comment: Hi @Slimer , could you try the data tag `data:blog.postImageUrl` instead of `data:view.featuredlmage` and see if that works. I have updated the answer to reflect this change

Comment: Hi @Prayag Verma, it worked! :) Thank-you so much for your help! :)